# how to convert datetime from mysql to doctrine2 odm in zf2?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i used doctrine2 Odm in zf2 but my update query store wrong result of date how i set date format in doctrine2 Odm?
here is my update query:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $form->setInputFilter($form->getInputFilter());
                $form->setData($post);
                //echo '<pre>';
                //print_r($post);
                //die();
                if($form->isValid())
                {
                    $formData=$form->getData();
                    $update=$dm->createQueryBuilder('Calendar\Document\Event')
                    ->update()
                    ->field('title')->set($post['title'])
                    ->field('description')->set($post['description'])
                    ->field('begin')->set(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post['begin']))
                    ->field('end')->set(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post['end']))
                    ->field('id')->equals($id)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->execute();

                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('calendar');
                    //return $this->redirect()->toRoute('calendar', array('action' => 'show', 'id' => $form->get('calendar_id')->getValue()));

                }
```

but it stores begin=1970-01-01 05:33:34 and end=1970-01-01 05:33:34,how i store correct date format like 6/19/2014 6:33:00 AM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
->field('begin')->set(new \DateTime($post['begin']))
```

Doctrine will format the data the right way.